# Cannot create a file

Tags: php, file-permissions

I am trying to create a file using php to a dirctory which has cmod 0777 so it should be fine.

Here is the code:

```
$fh = fopen("/_myfiles/myfile.txt", "w+");

if ($fh==false)
{
    die("unable to create file");
}
```

But all I get is `"unable to create file"`. Any ideas on what it could be?

Note: For the path I've also tried:

```
$fh = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/_myfiles/myfile.txt", "w+");
```

with no success.

Comment: could you paste logs ? if any..

Comment: You need to provide more info. PHP won't only say "Unable to create file", but it will also say _why_ it cannot create the file.

Comment: Is this on a shared host? Possibility of php fopen being disabled?

Comment: Most probably a permissions issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) generates an [`E_WARNING`](http://php.net/errorfunc.constants#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-warning) message on failure.

I recommend using [`error_reporting(E_ALL)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to show the warning and this should help you to troubleshoot the problem from there.

Answer (score 2):

Check write permissions on the directory you want to create the file in.

Also the directory "_myfiles" should exist (it won't be created automatically).

If they are correct, then this will create the file in the same directory where the PHP script is located:

```
$basedir = dirname(__FILE__);
$fh = fopen($basedir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'myfile.txt', 'w+');
```